Send/Receive Frequency in Modern Office 365 on Outlook from Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise
How often does modern Outlook in 2024 check for new emails?  Can that be verified locally?  Can that be changed, either locally or centrally?
Older versions of Outlook connected to Exchange to check for emails once per minute, and I thought that couldn't be changed.

I don't know if that setting is still available, but most mail apps allow the user to configure it:  https://docs.hostdime.com/hd/mail/changing-frequency-of-checking-email-in-outlook-and-thunderbird

In the modern Outlook from Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise as of 2024, the default frequency for checking new emails can vary. Typically, Outlook is set to check for new messages every 30 minutes, but this interval can be adjusted depending on your version of Outlook or any organizational policies that may be in place.
To verify and change the send/receive frequency locally in Outlook, you can follow these steps:
Open Outlook and click on the File menu.
Select Options and then click on the Advanced tab.
Look for the Send and receive section and click on the Send/Receive… button.
In the Send/Receive Groups dialog box, you can set your preferred frequency for checking new emails.
For centrally managing the send/receive frequency, this would typically be handled by your organization’s IT department through group policies or similar administrative tools.

It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.
